# PHP script works when called from command line, does not when called as background via web server

Tags: php, ffmpeg, xampp, background-process

I am facing a problem with a certain PHP script (CLI mode) I wrote. It should take certain arguments to convert a video with FFMPEG. When I call it from the command prompt, it works fine. However, I have to call it from a web server.

The PHP script that handles the request calls the PHP script in the background via code I found here at SE:

```
if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
    pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
} 
else { 
    exec("nohup " . $cmd . " > /dev/null &");
}
```

When run this way, however, the PHP script does not create the files, even after a much longer time than it took via the command prompt.

The script runs, I have checked that by letting it insert dummy entries into the database. It also has the permission to create files, which I verified by letting it create a text file.

What could be the difference that prevents my script from working properly? I develop and test this code with XAMPP on Windows 7.

//EDIT: I forgot to give you this link to the background PHP script: http://pastebin.com/pfTZMfwi

//EDIT2: I found out that the PHP process runs for a very short time (only until next refresh of the Windows task manager). Could it be that PHP kills its children when it exits?

//EDIT3: No, that seems not to be the problem. I cannot execute programs via exec() when the script is called as background from the web server. What could the problem be, and what would be a solution/workaround?

//EDIT4: The command that seems to cause the trouble is not exec()/etc. but the echo command I did before the exec(). I am going to remove it, but why does it cause a problem?

Comment: You should test your code on a virtual machine... who uses Windows machines on production anyway? I don't know what this "start" command does, but it might need some context about the current user, which the server daemon does not have. Have you tried other commands?

Comment: `start /B` starts a command in the background. It worked. What did not work was something in the launched program, which I in the meantime have figured out to be the `echo` command. I posted it with this context because the program worked fully normal when started via the command prompt.

Comment: My question is still: Why?

Comment: Does the user who executes the script has the permission to execute the ffmpeg binary? Maybe the script who starts this on background finishes and, once the parent has finished, all children processes are also terminated. It might run on background, but can still be attached to the parent. Try keeping `pclose` out to begin then wait a few seconds before returning, if that solves, you know what's the problem.

Comment: Also, why reinvent the wheel? https://github.com/alchemy-fr/PHP-FFmpeg, looks like a very nice API, it's simple and clean.

Comment: Probably it is misleading because the question was originally a different one, but the problem is not `ffmpeg`, but `echo` (the PHP statement). I still wonder why it made my script fail. I removed it and it works like charm, but I still want to know *why*. No solutions or workarounds, I have found one. I am seeking a reason.

Comment: Have you tried not closing the process and waiting a little bit before returning? It didn't worked? Maybe it keeps a buffer, once a few chars have been read only then it kills. Could be a Windows or PHP bug.

Comment: Try ``system`` instead of exec.

Comment: @George Y I tried both - as stated before, the problem was `echo`

Comment: @GeorgeY. Or you mean in the calling script? `exec` would never be executed, as on Windows the `popen()` would be used.

Comment: @RogielSulzbach I wrote an infinite loop after the call, the fact that it terminated anyway lead me to the conclusion I mentioned in the third edit.